# VideoJS player.autoCaption is not a function

Tags: javascript, html5-video, haml

I'm using VideoJS and am looking into ways to auto generate subtitles on videos. I have looked around and the only package / plugin I could find was `videojs-auto-caption`. https://github.com/mister-ben/videojs-auto-caption

I tried following the instructions, ie doing the following:

(1) `npm install --save videojs-auto-caption`
(2) `var player = videojs('id for video element here')`
(3) `player.autoCaption()`

However, when I try step #3, I get the error `player.autoCaption is not a function`. I'm not entirely sure what the issue here is because the videojs-auto-caption package is also included in my package.json file.

The code is as follows (it's in HAML):

```
%video#player{controls: "", width: 'auto', height: 'auto', preload: "metadata"}
:javascript
   var player = videojs('player');
   player.autoCaption();
```

console.log(player) also gets me the player element so I know it's not null. Am I missing something obvious here? Or perhaps there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: VideoJS is just a player. It **does not** auto generate subtitles on videos, for that you need some audio analysis (_ie:_ speech recognition) algorithm. `player.autoCaption()` is supposed to auto-select your subtitle file (VTT) based on the VideoJS player's language settings (_eg:_ If you set your player menu options to be French then it looks for VTT file with "french" or "fr" in file name)...

Comment: Ohh ok that was something I misunderstood. Are there any speech recognition APIs or sorts that could work well with VideoJS? I did some research & only found the Google Cloud Speech API